# The measure of an uncountable union of a family of open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given that $m$ is a regular measure and $\mathcal{O} = \{O_{\alpha}\}$ be an uncountable family of open sets.

Then certainly $\bigcup_{\alpha} O_{\alpha}$ is measurable since it is open.

I want to to prove that
$$ m(\bigcup_{\alpha}O_{\alpha}) = \sup \{ \sum_{i=1}^n m(O_{\alpha_i}) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } O_{\alpha_i} \in \mathcal{O} \}
$$

One direction of inequality is trivial, however I could not prove the other direction. Any hint please? Or maybe this equality is just false?

Edit:
I have to add the condition that $\{O_{\alpha}\}$ is a collection of disjoint sets, otherwise some comments and answers pointed out this equality is false.

Comment: If you replace the sum on the right side by $m(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}O_{\alpha_i})$ then this is true.

Comment: For $\alpha \in [0. 1] \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ under the usual measure, take $O_\alpha = [0, \alpha]$. Then $m(\bigcup_\alpha O_\alpha) = m([0, 1]) = 1$, but your $\sup$ is $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A regular measure on a topological space is a measure for which every measurable set can be approximated from above by open measurable sets and from below by compact measurable sets.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure)

So let $\mu$ be a regular measure.  We assume the sigma-algebra is the Borel sets (the OP doesn't say that, but does assume that open implies measurable).

Let $A = \mu(\bigcup_{\alpha} O_\alpha) \in (0,+\infty]$.  Let $B \in \mathbb R$ such that $B < A$.  By regularity, there is a compact measurable set $K \subset \bigcup_\alpha O_\alpha$ with $\mu(K) \ge B$.  By compactness, the open cover $O_\alpha$ of $K$ has a finite subcover $K \subseteq O_{\alpha_1}\cup\cdots\cup O_{\alpha_n}$.  Then
$$
B \le \mu(K) \le \mu(O_{\alpha_1})+\dots+\mu(O_{\alpha_n})
$$
Therefore
$$
\sup \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n m(O_{\alpha_i}) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } O_{\alpha_i} \in \mathcal{O} \right\} \ge B
$$
This is true for all $B < A$, so
$$
\sup \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n m(O_{\alpha_i}) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } O_{\alpha_i} \in \mathcal{O} \right\} \ge A = \mu\big(\bigcup_\alpha O_\alpha\big);
$$

Answer (score 1):

That is not true. Just imagine what will happen when all $O_\alpha$'s are equal.

Comment: +1. I almost posted an identical answer!

Comment: I think what the person is trying to ask is whether it is true for distinct uncountable open sets. If all $O_{\alpha}$'s are equal, then the family is only a singleton set.

Comment: It is false even if the open sets are distinct. For a related result that is true see my comment below the question. @AniruddhaDeshmukh

Comment: I guess to make this question nontrivial, we have to assume all sets are disjoint and distinct.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathscr{O}$ is an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open sets in $\Bbb R^n$, let $$\mathscr{O}_0=\{O\in\mathscr{O}:O\ne\varnothing\}\,;$$ then $\mathscr{O}_0$ is countable, since each member of $\mathscr{O}_0$ must contain a different element of $\Bbb Q^n$. That is, $\mathscr{O}$ has only countably many non-empty elements, and you might as well be working with the countable family $\mathscr{O}_0$ in the first place.

Of course all of this applies equally well to any separable metric space.

Comment: Good answer.  But the question does not say $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @GEdgar: I realize that and in fact originally wrote it for separable metric spaces in general, but all of the discussion has been in $\Bbb R$, so I decided to keep it simple.

Comment: This is slick, but @GEdgar answer is what I was looking for, so I decided to accept his answer.